# i want to replace series of numbers in my sql file how can i if i am using sublime text

Tags: sql, sublimetext3

```
(4197, 282, '342', 19, 1, 12, '0', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL),
(4194, 282, '331', 19, 1, 12, '1', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL),
(4189, 282, '336', 19, 1, 11, '0', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL),
(4193, 282, '332', 19, 1, 12, '1', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL),
(4192, 282, '333', 19, 1, 11, '0', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL),
(4160, 282, '350', 19, 3, 11, '0', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 1),
(4190, 282, '335', 19, 1, 12, '1', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL),
(4188, 282, '337', 19, 1, 12, '0', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL),
(4187, 282, '338', 19, 1, 12, '1', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL),
```

Here is some sample of the series 4197 to 4187 how can i replace it???

Comment: Do you want to replace them with the same replacement? Are they always at the start of  the line? Are all lines, where you want to replace the numbers are in conjunction?

Comment: Yes i exactly want that

Comment: You can just use multiple-cursor: select all lines, press ctrl+shift+l to split the selection into lines, then press pos1 (to jump to the begin of line), right arrow, ctrl+shift+right arrow, and write your text.

Comment: @r-stein Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To replace multiple instance of a same word in sublime you have to press Ctrl + D and select the multiple instance and you can edit all of them at once.

Alternatively you can use find and replace feature

Read more about multiple selection in sublime here: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html